# Is a browser a "stub resolver"?

Tags: domain-name-system

I have read the definition of "stub resolver" described in RFC1123, but I am still unclear.

As far as I know, in the DNS resolution the client uses a recursive resolver (which can be from the ISP or an external provider) to establish contact with the root server, the TLD nameserver and the authoritative nameserver. However, what exactly is the client's "stub resolver"?

I understand that the "stub resolver" is the one that connects to the "recursive resolver", but can a browser, such as Chrome or Firefox, act as a "stub resolver", or does the "stub resolver" depend on the operating system itself?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The *stub resolver* is the software component on the client side that just sends any and all DNS queries to a pre-configured recursive resolver server (with the *Recursion Desired* flag set in the queries), letting said server do all the work and then just using the response from said server.

Traditionally a normal application is not a stub resolver in itself, it rather just invokes `getaddrinfo` (or before that `gethostbyname`) to have the OS perform the name resolution and return the results. That is, the stub resolver has traditionally been an OS component.

Web browsers, however, are nowadays huge in scope and increasingly just bring along all the components they prefer. I do not feel confident that browsers still follow the general rule of how normal applications work, or if they have rather chosen to duplicate the stub resolver functionality (in that case presumably just reading the config parameters from the OS stub resolver).

Regardless how "normal" browsers are in general, Firefox when configured with its new [Trusted Recursive Resolver (TRR)](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Trusted_Recursive_Resolver) (DoH-based in-browser name resolution) mode enabled should probably be considered the stub resolver in itself.

TL;DR: If you had asked about applications in general the answer would have been a simple "no". Regarding browsers it's more of an "it's complicated".